# showing specific data in view file

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter, model

Here i have a view file where i can see information.Its works perfectly.But i want to see the view as login person.Suppose if male person logged in he will see female information. Female as like male.How can i do that??i am doing this in codeigniter.

main.php //controller

```
public function viewStd(){

        $data=array();
        $this->load->model('signup_model');
        $data['query1']=$this->signup_model->viewData();
        $this->load->view('view_std',$data);


    }
```

signup_model.php // model

```
 public function viewData(){

        $query=$this->db->get('std_info');
        return $query->result();


    }
```

view.php  //view

```
    <?php
 session_start();

if(!$this->session->userdata('id')){ //Here is the session start.
        redirect("login/checkLogin");}
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td><td>Email</td></tr>
    <?php 
foreach ($query1 as $student){
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($student);
?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $student->name?></td><td><?php echo $student->phone?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student->email?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: its not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: i want to show data as opposite gender.If male person logged in he will see female information.if female logged in she will see male information.In this above folder i can see both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said

> i want to show data as opposite gender.If male person logged in he
>   will see female information.if female logged in she will see male
>   information.

do that in the controller. check the gender and then call an appropriately named method.

```
if( $person->gender == 'male'){

  $this->showFemales($query1) ; } 

else {  $this->showMales($query1) ; }
```

And your session setting and checking should happen in the controller -- not the view.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to keep user data (logged in user) in session and lets consider you used CodeIgniter [session class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). In your login, you should keep data if loggedin user is male or female.. e.g 
`$this->session->setuserdata(Array('user_sex'=>$row['sex']));` 
Now in your `viewData()` model function, you should use a where clause to get your expected data like
 `$sex= $this->session->userdata('user_sex')=='male':'female'?'male';`
`$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('sex' => $sex));` This should give you exact result set you want to show in your view.